# Do we use the article in the word "very"?

Tags: articles

In this example, what articles do we use?

> "Who has got **a** flat?”  “They have.”
> “What kind of flat they have got?”
> “They have got **a** very big flat.”
> “Where is **a** flat?”
> “**A** flat is in Murmur Street.”

I want to use "the" but not sure about it.

Comment: "What kind of flat **have they** got?" You should use _the_ for the last two, since the speakers have established which flat they are talking about.

Comment: So in this example: "What kind of flat they have got?" we will answer "They have got the very big flat.”, right?

Comment: No, I said _the last two_ (and I showed you the right way to ask the question!). _They have [got] a very big flat_ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The article is for the noun, not for the adverb or the adjective. Take those away and you'd still use the article:

- A flat
- A big flat
- A very big flat

It isn't your use of adverbs or adjectives that determines which article to use - it is the noun and the context. Use the definite article when you are referring to something specific.

"I have a flat" is correct because you haven't specified which flat it is. However, once you have stated that you have 'a flat', it can now be distinguished from other flats because it is *yours*. So, you might say:

> I have **a** flat. **The** flat is big.

Comment: But why we cant say "the very big flat"?

Comment: @venro you can, in the right context.

Comment: When you say you have "a flat", you are referring to "*something specific*", so that's not the rule. The rule is to use "the" when you're referring to something previously *specified* in the context. "Specified" and "specific" aren't the same thing

Comment: So in this example: "What kind of flat they have got?" we will answer "They have got the very big flat.”, right?